# What's the distribution of fixed effects?

Tags: distributions, mixed-model

A general nonlinear mixed effect model for the $j$th observation on the $i$th individual is

$y_{ij} = f(\phi_i, x_{ij}) + e_{ij}$

$\phi_i = A_i\beta + B_ib_i$, where $b_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2D) $

I know that the random effects $b_i$ are normal with mean 0. Here, $\beta$ is a p-vector of fixed population parameters. What is the distribution of $\beta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed effects are not random variables thus do not have distributions, or their distributions are atomic. *Estimates* of fixed effects are statistics which have distributions.

Comment: I see. Could you elaborate on the distributions of the estimates of fixed effects?

Comment: Are they asymptotically normally distributed because they're maximum likelihood estimates? I am wondering because I am trying to simulate some data based on a nonlinear mixed effect model that I fit using `nlme` in R. For example, if my R output shows that the estimate and SE of fixed effect 1 is: 1.3 (0.3), would it be appropriate to sample from a N(1.3, 0.3) distribution in order to simulate data using this model?

Comment: @Adrian parameter estimates from linear models are normally distributed because of the Lindberg Feller Central Limit Theorem. I'm not sure of the theorems which give us such results in mixed effects models. The limiting normal theory for maximum likelihood is fairly complicated, and I don't know if mixed models meet all the regularity conditions.